# Why does the PHP run faster than MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, testing

I ran some simple tests: same complex query in mysql and php and measured the times taken to process them. The results are very controversial and suggest that some queries PHP processes faster than MySql.

In theory, shouldn't be the MySql faster? 
I am want compare how PHP (scripting language) interface decreases the performance of complex SQL query. But why my results suggest otherwise?

Those are averages, I run each query 3 times!

php code:

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("test3", $con);

    $start = microtime(TRUE);
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `test`
    ORDER BY `test`.`test1` DESC
    LIMIT 0,100");


echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>ID</th>
<th>test1</th>
<th>test2</th>
<th>test3</th>
<th>test4</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['ID'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Test1'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Test2'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Test3'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Test4'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "</table>";

$end = microtime(TRUE);

$sqlTime = $end - $start;


mysql_close($con);
echo $sqlTime
?>
```

The results: time in seconds against the number of records:
[image]

Comment: What is the schema for the table? I'm betting DateAccess doesn't have an index on it.

Comment: That's only one block of code, what are you comparing against?

Comment: are you comparing a database system with a programming language that can (but it is not required to or limited to) use that system by showing the time it takes for the programming language to output records from the database?

Comment: I even don't understand the question. How can you compare PHP and MySQL? What I see here is PHP code which issues a MySQL query.

Comment: I guess you are trying to say that the php sort() function is faster than the ORDER BY in mysql. Although your code doesn't show that. Furthermore, you are also measuring the time for the ouptut via echo etc.

Comment: I may be being dense here but according to your table isn't MySQL quicker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see you are using phpmyadmin, it is scripted too to return the values.This might be slow than the speed of your script which is definitely small. Did you consider to run the mysql queries from the command prompt?This might give you a clear difference.

Comment: So true, how can I do that? download from here http://www.mysql.com/? I am using  EasyPHP solution at the moment

Comment: try http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/windows-start-command-line.html

Comment: If you are in window environment,locate the mysql bin folder in your installation. Here is how I have done mine: open cmd,change directory to point to my path: as cd C:\xampp\mysql\bin\ then copy paste this replacing the username,pass and db by yours mysql --user=user_name --password=your_password db_name

Comment: also http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql.html: From that point you should be able to do your queries normally. You must be familiar with mysql syntax

Answer (score 1):

There can be numerous reasons why PHP runs faster than MySQL. If I put the MySQL server on my 2008 300$ lenovo netbook and run the PHP on my server, I even get much more speed differences.

The way how you formulated your question shows, that your understanding of performance measured in time in relation to some software only is the issue here.

Comment: Thanks so based on my evidence, no conclusions can be made? I thought that the more records would be on a table the longer it would take to process them because php is scripting language? and therefore, the PHP interface decreases the performance of MySQL

Comment: I'd say there even is no evidence in your question. Just run only the query and measure how long it takes - no output etc. Then do the same on an array (load the array from a file and sort it). You should start comparing those times. On the same machine. Repeat each test 100.000 times. Take the average. Ignore if times differ in the range of +/- 5%, that can be just because of what the computer was working with elsewhere.

Comment: I am working on same machine. How can I do this: **Then do the same on an array (load the array from a file and sort it)** Isn't want I am doing in my php code - microtime?

Comment: You php code contains microtime, but where do you measure the mysql query only and where do you measure the PHP array loading + sort? That's not even part of your question as far as I can see.